# Angular create directive with Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a new element within a service, compile it and append it to the body (a message box). 
My question is if and how it's possible to create a new element in a service and append it to the DOM and if there's a better way to do it maybe (it should be in a service tho).

My problem is that I can't bind attributes to the directive's scope:

I got the following code:

Method to create new element in my service

```
_createMessageBox = function (text, buttons) {
    var msgBox = document.createElement('message-box');
    msgBox.setAttribute('class', 'messageBox');
    msgBox.setAttribute('text', text);
    msgBox.setAttribute('buttons', buttons);
    $compile(msgBox)(scope);
    $('body').append(msgBox);               
};
```

Use of the service

```
var buttons = ['Eins', 'Zwei'];
mbs.createMessageBox('Nachricht', buttons);
```

directive

```
app.directive('messageBox', function () {
    link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.buttonClicked = function(id) {
            this.$emit('button'+id+'_clicked');
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:
        {
            text: '=',
            buttons: '='
        },
        link: link
        };
});
```

When I do it that way I get this error and the attributes aren't binded

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [Eins,Zwei] starting at [,Zwei].

Comment: why do you want it in service? is it because you want it accessible across all your controllers?
i see you are creating a directive element and then appending html elements to it like text and button what are you trying to achieve pls elaborate

Comment: Yes I want a service because of the accessibility.   A controller should be able to inject the service and then create a message box in certain use cases by using the method createMessageBox.   I'm not that deep in angular but I hope the approach is okay

Answer (score 1):

You have dependency on a directive and service so you should be using a provider not a service for this refer http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

secondly your directive has an isolated scope so even if you perform events at a controller level you wont be able to respond from the directive as per your requirements in the comments section i would advise you to use $modal service in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem,

```
msgBox.setAttribute('text', text);
msgBox.setAttribute('buttons', buttons);
```

this was just setting the attribute as a constant string, the solution was to create the property for the scope I created the element with plus I had to hand a string as attribute, not a variable

This code is working:

```
_createMessageBox = function (text, buttons) {
    scope.text = text;
    scope.buttons = buttons;
    var msgBox = document.createElement('ext-message-box');
    msgBox.setAttribute('class', 'extMessageBox');
    msgBox.setAttribute('text', 'text');
    msgBox.setAttribute('buttons', 'buttons');
    $compile(msgBox)(scope);
    $('body').append(msgBox);               
};
```